# ManyWho and Salesforce Integration -

Tags: salesforce

We are trying to create Salesforce pages using ManyWho.

-Can we create a Lookup field in ManyWho?
 -Can we show/hide the section dynamically in ManyWho?
 -Can we create dependent picklist in ManyWho flow?

If anyone knows the answer/any document for these questions. Please share.

Thanks in advance 
Raja

Answer (score 0):

You can use page conditions in ManyWho (Boomi Flow now) to show/hide sections.

You can find more content on using ManyWho and Salesforce here - https://docs.manywho.com/

HTH.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

We (Salesforce) have recently published two new unofficial Flow Screen Components that greatly improve your ability to declaratively do this.

See:

https://medium.com/@alexedelstein/dynamic-questions-in-lightning-flow-b0269ee373ce

https://medium.com/@alexedelstein/dependentpicklists-a-flow-screen-component-c97dcee1796